# React useState on form Submit - Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to Submit one input on submit not on OnChange event. So far I did below code:

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
        <Input className="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter To Do Items"/>
        <Button classProp="btn btn-warning btn-block">Submit</Button>
</form>

const [toDoName, setToDoName] = useState([]);

const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setToDoName( prevState => [
        ...prevState,
        event.target['name'].valueame
    ])
}
```

How can I set State on submit

Comment: what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I cannot Submit the value to state

Comment: is it coz you have a typo? `event.target['name'].valueame` what is `valueame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Synthetic events are pooled by React for reuse`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) and since you use the event value in the functional state update, it will throw you the error as the event values are cleared before the update happens. Save the value before updating the state or use `event.persist()` to persist the event values

```
const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = event.target['name'].valueame; // make sure you use correct property from event
    setToDoName( prevState => [
        ...prevState,
        value
    ])
}
```